# xpathで要素数が可変のデータを抽出する方法

Tags: python, python3, xpath

先月、質問をさせていただいた者です。質問は「[xpathでデータが未定義の箇所がある場合、どのように例外処理をすれば良いか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53390/xpath%e3%81%a7%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%81%8c%e6%9c%aa%e5%ae%9a%e7%be%a9%e3%81%ae%e7%ae%87%e6%89%80%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%ae%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e4%be%8b%e5%a4%96%e5%87%a6%e7%90%86%e3%82%92%e3%81%99%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0%e8%89%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b)」で、これに続く内容です。
使っている元データは科研費のDBで https://kaken.nii.ac.jp/ からアクセスしてXMLデータとしてダウンロードできます。ダウンロードしたXMLから必要なデータだけを抽出して、CSVファイルを作っています。
当初の目的は達成し、うまく動くようになったのですが、機能を拡張していく中で、別のことも必要になってきました。

例えば https://kaken.nii.ac.jp/search/?kw=KAKENHI-PROJECT-18K09063 から、画面上の方にある[XMLで出力]の隣の実行ボタンを押してXMLデータをダウンロードすると、

```
<grantAward>
    <summary xml:lang="ja">
        <member sequence="1" eradCode="60196904" role="principal_investigator">～
        <member sequence="2" eradCode="10508526" role="co_investigator_buntan">～
        <member sequence="3" eradCode="20378285" role="co_investigator_buntan">～
```

のように、sequenceが1, 2, 3～順に並ぶ、メンバーリストがある構造になっています。ここで、前回の処理と並行して各summaryに、

・sequenceが何番まであるのか探索して数値を出力する
・sequence=1～n内の情報(ここではeradCode)を連続出力(TAB区切り)する

ことが出来ないか考えています。sequenceの数は定められておらず、可変です。（大半のデータは1ですが、大きいものだと50超のものもあります）

今試しているコードは下記のような状態です（本当はもっと長いですが、短縮してあります）。

```
from lxml import etree      # lxmlライブラリを使用
tree = etree.parse('ファイル名')
root = tree.getroot()

awards = tree.xpath('/grantAwards/grantAward')

LstGrantid  = list()
LstErad     = list()
LstMembers  = list()

if len(awards):
    for m in awards:
        # 科研費ID
        grantid  = m.xpath('@id')
        eradname = m.xpath('summary[@xml:lang="ja"]/member[@sequence="1"]/@eradCode')

        # 取得した要素をリスト変数へ代入
        if len(grantid):        # 科研費ID
            LstGrantid.append(grantid[0])
        else:
            LstGrantid.append("")

        if len(eradname):       # 1st名前（Erad）
            LstErad.append(eradname[0])
        else:
            LstErad.append("")

        # 共同研究者リストを作る　★うまくいっていない
        memberlst = tree.xpath('/grantAwards/grantAward/summary[@xml:lang="ja"]/member')
        if len(memberlst):
            for n in memberlst:
                membersu = n.xpath('member[@sequence=n]/@eradCode') # メンバー（Erad）
                if len(membersu):
                    LstMembers.append(membersu[0])
                else:
                    LstMembers.append("")
            print(len(LstMembers), end='\t')    # 共同人数


    # 結果をTAB区切りで標準出力
    for j in range(len(LstGrantid)):
        print(str(LstGrantid[j]), end='\t')     # 科研費ID
        print(str(LstErad[j]), end='\t')        # 1st名前（Erad）

#        print(len(LstMembers), end='\t')   # ★うまくいっていない
        print()
```

結果はTAB区切りあるいはカンマ区切りで、人数(11)の後、Eradを羅列するもの：
KAKENHI-PROJECT-18K09063    60196904    11  10508526    20378285    20422826    20727664    40308664    40444442    50362687    50467362    60647121    80763739

人数(11)の後、Eradと名前を羅列するもの：
KAKENHI-PROJECT-18K09063    60196904    11  10508526    西村 明展   20378285    淺沼 邦洋   20422826    明田 浩司   20727664    竹上 徳彦   40308664    長谷川 正裕  40444442    辻井 雅也   50362687    若林 弘樹   50467362    中村 知樹   60647121    内藤 陽平   80763739    刀根 慎恵

を考えています。よろしくお願いいたします。

（質問の追記１）
データが１件ならば動くのですが、複数件あるとエラーが出てしまう
kaken.nii.ac.jp/search/?o1=1&s1=2018&s2=2018&s3=1 から、画面にある[XMLで出力]隣の実行ボタンを押してXMLデータをダウンロードしたものは
File "test.py", line 33, in  membersu = n.xpath('@eradCode')[0] IndexError: list index out of range
になってしまう。

※eradCodeを持っていない研究者の方がいるため

（質問の追記２）
新し目のデータにも未登録になるケースがある。
（１）名前だけ羅列するモード（Eradの有無は考慮しない）
（２）Eradだけ羅列するモード（Erad未登録のものはスキップする）
（３）Eradと名前を合わせて羅列し、Erad未登録者についてはEradの部分をnullにして、名前だけ出す
といったアプローチが考えられる。また、の方にしか personalName/fullName がないケースがあるようだ。

※名前がなけれは出力なし、として対応した

Comment: 出力されてほしい結果の例を提示いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 先日はありがとうございました！最後に結果の例を追記しました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もうちょっとのところまで実装できてそうです。
`for n in memberlst:`のループの中の`n`がどんな状態か、というところがポイントですね。

`n`の時点で`member`タグが一番上位になっているので、xpathで要素を取得するときは、子要素なり属性なりを指定するだけでよいはずです(memberタグの指定はいらない)。

ついでに、First Authorだけをxpathで取得する必要もないかもしれません。

First Author以外の著者のEradと名前を羅列するなら、以下のような感じだと思います。
名前が不要なら`name`関連の処理を消してください。

```
from lxml import etree      # lxmlライブラリを使用
tree = etree.parse('./kaken.nii.ac.jp_2019-04-12_00-34-28.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

awards = tree.xpath('/grantAwards/grantAward')

records =list()

if len(awards):
    for award in awards:

        record = list()

        # 科研費ID
        grant_id  = award.attrib.get('id') or ''
        record.append(grant_id)

        # 研究者リストを作る
        members = award.xpath('summary[@xml:lang="ja"]/member')
        for m in members:

            # eradCodeがない場合は空文字で補間
            eradCode = m.attrib.get('eradCode') or ''                  
            seq =  m.attrib.get('sequence') or ''          

            try:
                name = m.xpath('personalName/fullName').pop().text
            except IndexError:
                name = ''

            if seq == "1": # first author の処理
                record.append(eradCode)
                record.append(str(len(members)))
            else:
                record.append(eradCode)
                record.append(name)

        records.append(record)

#結果をTAB区切りで標準出力
for r in records:
    print('\t'.join(r))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！「first authorのスキップ」がなかなか技巧的ですね。
試したところデータが１件ならば動くのですが、複数件あるとエラーが出てしまうようです。

例えば
https://kaken.nii.ac.jp/search/?o1=1&s1=2018&s2=2018&s3=1
から、画面にある[XMLで出力]隣の実行ボタンを押してXMLデータをダウンロードしたものは

File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    membersu = n.xpath('@eradCode')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

になってしまいます。

Comment: どうもeradCodeを持っていない研究者の方がいるようですね。（roleがforeign_research_fellowの方）そこの処理をどうしたいかによると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。たしかにそういうパターンも考慮しないといけないですね。新しく入れたばかりのものでも、未登録になるケースがあります。
とすれば、やり方としては、

（１）名前だけ羅列するモード（Eradの有無は考慮しない）
（２）Eradだけ羅列するモード（Erad未登録のものはスキップする）
（３）Eradと名前を合わせて羅列し、Erad未登録者についてはEradの部分をnullにして、名前だけ出す
、が考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: とりあえず(3)で直してみました。あとはお好きに改造して使ってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。データの状態にばらつきがあるようで、このようなエラーが出てしまうケースがあるようです。2017年度のもの全件で試しています。何か良いデバックの方法はあるものでしょうか。　Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\科研費データPBI\kakendb-chushutsu2019-04.py", line 191, in <module>
    name = n.xpath('personalName/fullName')[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: 2017年度だけでは件数が多すぎるので、条件を絞って特定してみました。ここでエラーが出ます＞https://kaken.nii.ac.jp/search/?o1=1&s1=2017&s2=2017&fc=ca%3A%E5%A5%A8%E5%8A%B1%E7%A0%94%E7%A9%B6%2F000063

Comment: どうやら<summary xml:lang="en">の方にしか personalName/fullName がないケースがあるようで、そこで落ちるみたいですね。jaが無い場合にはenから取ってくるという仕組みが理想的ですが、そこまでしなくても、jaにない場合、nullにしてしまうとかで回避可能でしょうか。

Comment: とりあえず更新してみました（名前がなけれは出力なし）。
ただ、これ以上、質問に書いていないことをコメントのやり取りで反映していくのに限界を感じています。質問を修正していくか、小さな単位で別の質問を立てたりした方がよいのではないかと思います。

Comment: 問題の大半が解決しましたので、完了にさせていただきます。色々なテクニック、とても参考になりました。どうもありがとうございました！また、追加で細かい質問になってしまい、申し訳ありません（実データを入れると予想外のことが頻発するものですから・・・）ここでのやり取りを質問文の方に反映しました。